# Rails – Bundle install problems with json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, gcc, rubygems, osx-mavericks

I'm running OS X Mavericks, with Rails 3.2.12. When I try to do rails new project, it gets stuck at bundle install.

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make
compiling generator.c
make: gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I get the same error when I do 'gem install json....' as it suggests. I've installed the latest version of Xcode, with the command line tools. When I do:

```
which gcc
```

I get:

```
/usr/bin/gcc
```

I'm new to all this stuff really, so please try to keep things simple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, prior to XCode 5, there was a gcc-4.2 binary, which got removed in the upgrade.

I found this [tutorial](http://new-bamboo.co.uk/blog/2013/10/24/3-quick-tips-for-coding-with-os-x-10-9-mavericks) helpful in getting gcc-4.2 back and running with ruby. It assumes that you're using [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to manage packages on your Mac.

Comment: the first link you shared, helped me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Hi,I was getting exactly same error related to json on rails 4 on windows. I didn't hear about this xcode. Is it something related to MACOs? I couldn't decide if installing it on windows will fix my problem too ??